# emulate XMLHttpRequest client using PHP

Tags: php

For testing where should i give the url of the site, can you show me with the example in the above code?

```
$r = new HTTPRequest("server.php", HTTP_METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('omg' => 'wtf'));
$r->send();
var_dump($r->getResponseCode());
var_dump($r->getResponseBody());
```

Comment: you said `For testing`, if you dont want to install extra HTTP extension, you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if you have enabled it.

Comment: i'll try curl. Cant get PHP to detect http extension even though its installed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [addHeaders()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.addheaders.php).

The XMLHttpRequest is the value of the `X-Requested-With` header, so you just have to do:

```
$r = new HTTPRequest("http://mywebservices.com/somewebserver.php", HTTP_METH_POST); 
$r->addHeaders(array('X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
```

Instructions for installing HTTP from PECL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.setup.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but am not familiar with the codes ,if i need to check a site for example http://example.com where i need to place these url

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the bit where the URL is entered.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'HTTPRequest' not found in /var/www/html/gomo/request.php on line 3

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your URL. `openfirms.com.com/server.php` does not exist and `openfirms.com/server.php` results in a 404. Check their documentation to ensure you have the correct URL.

Comment: I think you'll have to check if the extension has been installed or not.

Comment: @Sanjay is on the ball. Didn't see your other comment with the error before. I have updated the answer with a link to installing the HTTP extension. Installation on linux should be quite straight forward.

Comment: sorry,, its openfirms.com and in the place of somewebserver.php what should i give ?

Comment: Well, that would depend on a lot of things. Are you trying to talk to a webservice? Or are you just trying to load the home page? If you just put in `http://openfirms.com/`, that would fire a request to `http://openfirms.com/index.php` or `http://openfirms.com/index.html`, or something else depending on how their server is set up.

Comment: thanks for reply,, but still errors... i told before am not at all familiar with codes,, and what i need is just to run that above code without errors while testing with a url.

Comment: If you are still seeing those errors, that means you do not have the HTTP extension for PHP enabled or installed. See the link in my answer on how to do this.

Comment: Yes, seems like my php isnt detecting it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

phpdev has answered your question very well, and if you install the HTTP extension and do it as according to the answer it will surely work.

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://your-required-url-here', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('omg' => 'wtf'));
echo $r->send()->getBody();
```

The urls given by you in the previous comments are not well formed, it seems that you have pasted some random URL.

This is just another way to do it with php CURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.openfirms.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array('omg' => 'wtf');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_R($output);
```

This will output the contents of specified url. Hope it will help